# Failed to collect dependencies at

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm just trying to understand something. Suppose I'm trying to pull in this dependency

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.thirdwatch</groupId>
<artifactId>mvn-to-cpe</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.racic.testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-configuration-manager</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mvn-to-cpe: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.thirdwatch:mvn-to-cpe:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at ch.racic.testing:test-configuration-manager:jar:0.9.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.racic.testing:test-configuration-manager:jar:0.9.5: Failure to find ch.racic.testing:test-configuration-manager-parent:pom:0.9.5 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

It seems the .jar is missing. We're using a Nexus server on our end and this is what it shows

[image]

I believe Nexus mirrors the Central Maven Repo and the central maven seems to have it.

See

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/racic/testing/test-configuration-manager/0.9.5/

and

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cch.racic.testing%7Ctest-configuration-manager%7C0.9.5%7Cjar

What is accounting for this discrepancy?
Are we mirroring the wrong maven repository?

[image]

Comment: @EGHM pointed out that version 0.9.4 has a jar and that version 0.9.5 uses a parent pom. I don't know if the parent pom has anything to do with it, but we suspect it might...

Comment: Sorry just saw this now, Yes it seems there is something wrong in how I deploy it... I'm trying to find out what because the deploy log tells me it has been uploaded to maven central (the parent pom artifact) but not sure why it ends up not being there. Seems 0.9.5-SNAPSHOT is there but not on the release version

Comment: Ok seems it somehow gets stuck in staging, they get uploaded but never promoted if its not a snapshot

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue in the pom files when switching to a multimodule project, it did stage all but only auto released the core artifact...

This is fixed now and 0.13.2 includes all the artifacts, sorry for the inconvenience but the unit tests did not cover that one and I have noted it as install did run well and so I could use it on my machine :-/

Comment: Btw. I did not add any documentation yet, so the unit tests are the documentation but if needed I can document it when I get some time?

Comment: Btw. the problem was that the other artifacts were missing the gpg plugin to create a signature and this got rejected during promotion from the staging to prod, moved that plugin config into the parent now that it gets inherited by all sub modules